# Display images from a folder on website dynamically. Foreach using Smarty

Tags: image, dynamic, foreach, smarty, directory

I want to display random images from a folder on my website
example: ../images/
I already thought of using a foreach construction only I don't know how to implement it in the code.

```
<ul>
{foreach from=../images/ item=imagelink}

<li><img src="{$imagelink}" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></li>

{foreach}
</ul>
```

I hope someone has a solution I already searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

I also want to show lateron all the images that are in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create your list of random images in PHP, then assign the array to a Smarty variable. Then you'll be able to iterate over the array with a foreach and create your list elements.

```
<?php

// create array of random images into $images
$smarty->assign(images, $images);

?>
```

```
{* template *}
<ul>
    {foreach from=$images item=image}
        <li><img src="{$image}"/></li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@paul-delre working properly, so I take the url of all the images in that directory use

```
$files = glob("img/*.*");
```

and

```
$smarty->assign(images, $files);
```

Thanks for your help :-)